# how to delete single row using php

Tags: php, mysql

Dear please help me 
i am getting some error in my code

this is my view.php page

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table  style="border:#333 solid"  border="2">
         <tr>
            <td>ID:</td>
            <td>NAME:</td>
            <td>EMAIL:</td>
            <td>MOBILE:</td>
            <td>EDIT:</td>
            <td>DELETE:</td>
         </tr>
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
$query="select * from emp";
$conn=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if(isset($conn))
{
  echo"This is all data of table.";
}
else
{
  die("query is not execute". mysqli_error());  
}   

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn))
 {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_address'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emp_salary'] ?></td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['emp_id'];?>"><font   color="#FF0000">EDIT</font></a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['emp_id'];?>"><font   color="#FF0000">DELETE</font></a></td>
  </tr>
 <?PHP
 }
 ?>
       </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

and this is my delete.php file:

```
  <?php 
  include_once('connect.php');
  $id=$_GET['emp_id'];
  $query="delete from emp where emp_id='$id'";
  $del=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  if($del)
  {
    echo"record has been deleted";  
  }
  else
  {
    die("Record is not deleted it is query error.".mysqli_error()); 
  }
  ?>
```

How can I access the ID of the view.php in the delete.php file and how to delete a single row in my db table.
I don't understand how to access the id of view.php.
In this program I don't delete the selected row. Please tell me how to delele data.
please anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending `edit.php?id=` so need to get `id` from query string using `GET['id']`

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: can you explain which id we can use here $_GET['ID']

Comment: it is database column name ?

Comment: delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['emp_id'];?> so id= youremp_id which you are sending. No it's not db column name it's a query string variable

Comment: i understand. we can access using $_POST['id'] ? if no why?

Comment: cause you are not posting any data you are sending as query string which will get using GET

Answer (score 1):

change the code in delete.php as follow

```
 <?php 
 include_once('connect.php');
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $query="delete from emp where emp_id='$id'";
 $del=mysqli_query($con,$query);
 if($del)
 {
     echo"record has been deleted";   
 }
 else
 {
     die("Record is not deleted it is query error.".mysqli_error());  
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please also realize that using `$_GET` data within your queries is only asking for trouble, especially when it's not escaped properly. You're opening your self up to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Make use of `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're going to be using `mysql_*` functions, just realize that it has been deprecated in [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

You also have the option of using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) would be preferable since they both make use of prepared statements as mentioned in this previous question [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)